# How to send Parameter/Query in HubConnection SignalR Core

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to add parameter into connection to signalr.

I'm using Builder to create my Client connection and start it:

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("http://10.0.2.162:5002/connection")
        .WithConsoleLogger()
        .WithMessagePackProtocol()
        .WithTransport(TransportType.WebSockets)
        .Build();

await connection.StartAsync();
```

I want to send a simple parameter in this connection:
Something Like:

"Token": "123"

In my server side i think i can take this parameter from HttpContext:

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var httpContext = Context.Connection.GetHttpContext();
    var token = httpContext.Request.Query["Token"];
    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Any idea of how to send this parameter?
Thanks.

Comment: Note that on the latest version, it would be: `var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext()`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have found how to do this after much research:

On my build i just send the token from url connection.
Like this:

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl($"http://10.0.2.162:5002/connection?token={token}")
        .WithConsoleLogger()
        .WithMessagePackProtocol()
        .WithTransport(TransportType.WebSockets)
        .Build();
```

Comment: Works like a charme :). Thx.

Comment: do you have to make some kind of change to the endpoint mapping for the MessageHub on the server? I'm getting a 400 response