# SignalR Core How to get a connection parameter server side

Tags: .net-core, signalr

As follow this answer [How to send Parameter/Query in HubConnection SignalR Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038762/how-to-send-parameter-query-in-hubconnection-signalr-core)

I'm setting the client :

```
const connectionHub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl(Constants.URL_WEB_SOCKET + '?token=123')
.build();
```

but how to get the token value server side?

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    _connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    var token = Context.Items["token"]; // this is null

    var token2 = Context.QueryString["token"]; // 'HubCallerContext' does not contain a definition for 'QueryString' 

    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get token value in **.net core**, you can use the following code:

```
var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
var tokenValue = httpContext.Request.Query["token"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a parameter in QueryString.

In your client, declare a string dictionary and connection

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _querystringdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private HubConnection _connection;
private const string HubUrl = "your hub url";
```

Then, assign the value you want to send

```
 _querystringdata.Add("key", "Value");
 _connection = new HubConnection(HubUrl, _querystringdata);
```

Start the connection

```
if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
        {

            // Creating the signalrHub proxy
            IHubProxy signalrHub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("SignalrHub");
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Connection");
            // starting the signalr connection
            _connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");

                    //Client methods which server can invoke
                    signalrHub.On<dynamic>("sendMessage", (data) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Message:- {0}", data);
                        // do something
                    });
                }
            }).Wait(); 
        }
```

then in your server signalR hub class

```
 public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            // getting the value sent with query string
            var token = Context.QueryString.Get("Key");
            // do something like connection mapping etc
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return (base.OnConnected());
    }
```

Comment: No, Constants.URL_WEB_SOCKET is my web socket Url (i.e http://localhost:4545/enginehub).

And Context do not contain a definition of QueryString

Comment: That's  because you didn't assign a QueryString in your client. I've updated the answer. Hope this helps.